# Get path to built files programmatically

Tags: ros, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have add_custom_commands to build files that will be loaded at run time by a ros node.  Right now those files get put into `build/my_package/`.  Is there a combination of a destination to provide cmake and something like ros::package::getPath() that will allow me to load the files regardless of whether using catkin_make install or devel.

The solution I don't want is to build the files into the source directory.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254335/get-path-to-built-files-programmatically/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2017-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A solution that doesn't involve build artifacts in the source tree could be to turn the generated files into a library or add it to the executable- convert the binary files into header files like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707183/script-tool-to-convert-file-to-c-c-source-code-array

```
xxd -i my_cmake_generated_file.bin > my_cmake_generated_file.h
```

Which produces:

```
unsigned char my_cmake_generated_file[] = {
0x46, 0x53, 0x48, 0x04, 0xa4, 0x8b, 0xef, 0x49, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0x00,
...
  0x6f, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x30, 0x3b, 0x0a, 0x7d, 0x0a, 0x0a, 0x00
};
unsigned int my_cmake_generated_file_len = 83;
```

And then code that loads a binary into a byte array could be simplified to just use this from the header file directly

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0